# How do I store textbox inputs in a number format into a list?

Tags: c#, arrays

This is the assignment:

Task 1- Write a Windows application that accepts any number of positive values, that is inputted by a button. The user clicks another button to process all the inputted data at any time. The resulting output should be:

first output - sum of all the n entered numbers,

second output - on a listview show two columns with the following information-

column1 - the inputted numbers,

column2 - the percentages contributed by each number to the sum.

So far I have this:

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    double number = 0, total = 0, numDisplay;
    string[] numbers;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {

        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        if (number > 0)
        {
            total += number;
            textBox1.Text = number.ToString();
            numDisplay = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) { }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '.' && textBox1.Text.IndexOf(".") == -1) { }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "sum: " + total.ToString();
    }
}
```

Basically, the only thing I need to finish is making the 2 last columns.. soo..

Taking into account that I am totally new to this program...
How can I take numbers that are inputted into a textbox and store them, but show them on a listview when you press the button? I would like to store whatever amount... meaning the list would be looped.

So for example if I placed 1,2,3,4,5 as my inputs, I want it to show in my first column in my list view as 1-5 going down my first column and for my secound column I would like the percentages of the numbers to the sum so in this case of 1-5, 
1/15
(1+2+3+4+5=15),
2/15,
3/15,
4/15,
5/15 
all times by 100

Comment: The community would be more likely to help you out if you say what you have done/tried so far. Showing that you have made some effort goes a long way.

Comment: A tip, Wrap the double.Parse( .. ) with   try catch blocks to catch parse errors from non numerics.

Comment: at levibotelho i just dont know where to start.. I am just lost when it comes to understanding arrays.. i know im suppose to use arrays but i can't seem to find any information on storing or listing numbers on a listview

Comment: @ christoffer lette yeah i reposted a older post because i was hoping that the community could help me with where i'm stuck at

Comment: @PechengChang next time try to format your question and be specific to avoid negative comment or downvote to your question.

Comment: okay sorry .. I am just starting this class and its a accelerated class.. so i am falling behind a bit. thanks for your kindness spajce

Comment: oh i didnt know.. i thought it was kudos for someone trying to help.. like a like button or something.

Comment: Then perhaps you should read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @ChristofferLette how could you say that my answer is clearly wrong `:D`

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

The question is not very clear. Thanks to Mr. @ChristofferLette, I realized, when or what if we want to enter a number like `15 21 12 24 and etc` but the OP's `TextBox` had a function that to allow the *number only*.

This will be the solution and suggestion, The function of `TextBox` should we allow the *`,`* and *backspace* and *all numbers*, the hints is, we need to separate the numbers, so we can get the *two, three or four etc*. digits number and apply the [`.RegEx Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
                && e.KeyChar != ',')
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Then,

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        var text = Regex.Split(textBox1.Text, @"\D+");
        var t = text.Select(c => decimal.Parse(c)).Sum(); //<--Get all the total
        foreach (var i in text)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Text = i;
            item.SubItems.Add(((decimal.Parse(i) / t) * 100).ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }

        //decimal total = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
        //                         .Select(c => decimal.Parse(c.SubItems[1].Text))
        //                         .Sum();

        //ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem();
        //item2.Text = "Total:";
        //item2.SubItems.Add(total.ToString("#,#0.00"));
        //listView1.Items.Add(item2);
    }
```

Comment: so if i want this to be on a listview tool how would i do that. i don't want it on a label1.text..

Comment: my answer is updated. please check.

Comment: @spajce Well, let's start with the magic number 15... Will every possible input have the sum of 15? Very likely not.

Comment: thanx for that tips mr. @ChristofferLette, because the OP is not telling about dynamically number. `:D`

Comment: i would actually like subitems to be divided by the total sum how is that possible

Comment: @PechengChang see my updated answer.. about to get the total